# Why won't swiftmailer take the env vars?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, swiftmailer, phpdotenv

I'm trying to configure swiftmailer to send emails from my symfony4 app, from my local environment (Wamp, win10) with gmail.

The configuration works well when I add all my parameters in the config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml file but as soon as I try to use the .env file variables, it doesn't work and I'm getting this error:

```
14:01:11 DEBUG     [php] Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
[
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext {
    +count: 1
    -severity: E_WARNING
    trace: {
      C:\wamp\www\crm-granger\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:267 { …}
      C:\wamp\www\crm-granger\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:58 { …}
    }
  }
]
14:01:11 DEBUG     [php] Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
14:01:11 DEBUG     [php] Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error)
14:01:11 ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

Works :

config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:        smtp
    username:         myemail@gmail.com
    password:         mypassword
    host:             smtp.gmail.com
    port:             465
    encryption:       ssl
    auth-mode:        login
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed: true
            verify_peer: false
            verify_peer_name: false
```

Doesn't work:

.env

```
MAILER_TRANSPORT=smtp
MAILER_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAILER_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAILER_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAILER_PORT=465
MAILER_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:        '%env(MAILER_TRANSPORT)%'
    username:         '%env(MAILER_USERNAME)%'
    password:         '%env(MAILER_PASSWORD)%'
    host:             '%env(MAILER_HOST)%'
    port:             '%env(MAILER_PORT)%'
    encryption:       '%env(MAILER_ENCRYPTION)%'
    auth-mode:        login
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed: true
            verify_peer: false
            verify_peer_name: false
```

The vars appear and are well set when I do :

```
php bin/console about
```

```
bin/console debug:config swiftmailer
```

give me this :

```
Current configuration for extension with alias "swiftmailer"
============================================================

swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default
    mailers:
        default:
            transport: '%env(MAILER_TRANSPORT)%'
            username: '%env(MAILER_USERNAME)%'
            password: '%env(MAILER_PASSWORD)%'
            host: '%env(MAILER_HOST)%'
            port: '%env(MAILER_PORT)%'
            encryption: '%env(MAILER_ENCRYPTION)%'
            auth_mode: login
            spool:
                type: memory
                path: 'C:\wamp\www\my-project\var\cache\dev/swiftmailer/spool'
                id: null
            stream_options:
                ssl:
                    allow_self_signed: true
                    verify_peer: false
                    verify_peer_name: false
            delivery_addresses:
                - myemail@gmail.com
            url: null
            command: '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'
            timeout: 30
            source_ip: null
            local_domain: null
            logging: true
            delivery_whitelist: {  }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: maybe `spool: { type: memory }` is missing in your `swiftmailer.yaml` file (the one that doesn't work obviously)

Comment: or `auth-mode` is missing?

Comment: No, those parameters are set, I just didn't rewrite them...

Comment: Hmm weird - I do this all the time and it works fine. What are the results of 
`bin/console debug:config swiftmailer`???

Comment: Does the email work when you use the MAILER_URL convention?

Comment: Edited the post to add the swiftmailer config debug and no, the MAILER_URL doesn't work but I guess it's because I need  the stream options and I couldn't find a way to add them to the URL

Answer (score 0):

your yaml file will overwrite the .env file.
So keep with the Yaml config. It's more detailed and logical.

Answer (score 0):

no there is stupid configuration resolver and when env used

```
        stream_options:
            ssl:
                allow_self_signed: true
                verify_peer: false
                verify_peer_name: false
```

and much more is ignored...